# Unable to connect to the server when using ansible

Tags: ssh, ansible

I created a droplet using `digitalocean` and I'm able to connect to my droplet using `ssh root@37.139.14.547` without problems.

I just downloaded ansible and added this in my `/etc/ansible/hosts`:

`root@37.139.14.547`

Afterwards I'm running `ansible all -m ping` but I receive an error:

```
root@37.139.14.547 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey).\r\n", 
    "unreachable": true
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to tell ansible that my ssh public key is located in `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` or something?

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you've got all the packages installed at you local machine...
`pip install --user --upgrade setuptools`
`pip install --user --upgrade ansible`

Check the updates;
````` ansible --version ```` `````
ansible 2.3.2.0
  config file = 
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
  python version = 2.7.10 (default, Feb  7 2017, 00:08:15) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] ```

Also in your remote as the Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS on AWS doesn't come with the python installed, so ssh into remote server and run this before connect to your remote.
`sudo apt-get install python-minimal -y`

I am using EC2 as my remote server
Then try this...
`[webserver]
37.170.254.200 ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/username/.ssh/my_key.pem`

Make sure you can connect to you remote as ssh -i "my_key.pem`" ubuntu@37.170.254.200
If you can connect "SUCCESS", run the " ansible Ad-Hoc Commands " to ping

`ansible webserver -m ping -u ubuntu`

`37.170.254.200 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false, 
    "ping": "pong"
}`

OR try to check the memory usage of your remote
`ansible webserver -a "free -m" -u ubuntu`

If "SUCCESS" you are connect to your remote server

Answer (score -1):

Please read how [Ansible inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html) looks like.

Change your hosts to:

```
37.139.14.547 ansible_user=root
```